# Particle or preposition

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

Is "looking forward" in this sentence an adverb? Is *to* in this sentence a particle, a preposition, or neither?

> I am looking forward to getting a good job?

Comment: Can a particle function as an adverb because it seems that (looking forward+ to) has a similar meaning to (excited+ about).  So in both instances it appears there is an adverb and a preposition.

Comment: As a side note, this is not a question so there should not be a ? at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the  “Verb + particle + preposition (particle-prepositional phrasal verbs)” section of wikipedia's [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#Examples) article:

> b. She is looking forward to a rest. – forward is a particle and to is a preposition.

Also see example c in the [catenae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb#Catenae) section of that article, which provides a dependency grammar tree illustration of  “looking forward to”.

Answer (score 0):

The adverb is *forward*; "look forward to something" is a phrasal verb that means, "to be thinking with pleasure about something that is going to happen."
In this case, *forward* is a particle, and *to* is a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking forward to getting a good job.

In this sentence ***looking forward to*** is a Phrasal Verb.

In *looking forward to getting a good job*, the verb - *look* - takes two complements - one, an intransitive preposition, *forward* and two, a Preposition Phrase (PP) - *to getting a good job*.

In the second complement, inside the PP structure, the head Preposition is *to* and it takes a Gerund-Participle clause as a complement - *getting a good job*.

Structure of Gerund-Participle clause - *getting a good job*. The verb is *getting*, and the verb is taking a Noun Phrase (NP) as complement - *a good job*.